# Anaconda update broke Spyder?

Tags: pyqt, anaconda, spyder, conda

I ran the Anaconda Launcher (Windows 7) and clicked "Update" next to each thing, and now Spyder doesn't work.  It pops up this error message:

```
---------------------------
Spyder
---------------------------
Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt4 4.6+ (or PySide 1.2.0+) is required.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

but that's already met:

```
>conda update pyqt
Fetching package metadata: ....
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Jonathan\Anaconda:
#
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py27_0
```

I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be a bug that the Anaconda developers are working on. It was brought up here.
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/DM3pbxrb_ps/llEAnH00DwAJ

Your best choice is to downgrade PyQT4 until it is fixed. Just run the following command.

```
conda install pyqt=4.10
```

Comment: The above solution can also work when Anaconda Navigator fails to launch.